# Skateboard, roller blades or?

Tags: commuter

So this isn't precisely about bicycles but it's pretty close, right? Please point me to a more relevant Stack Exchange forum if there is one.

I am trying to optimize my daily commute. I usually walk slightly over a kilometer (slightly under a mile) to the station I depart from and about the same distance from the station I arrive at to my destination.

There are buses, but those are a bad option due to heavy traffic. I can rent a city bicycle for my "home - station" segment, but not for the other segment. So I settled on bying a... "personal transportation device"? (is there a word for it?)

There are lots of them on the market: skateboards, bikes, electric skateboards and electric bikes, roller blades, [Skyrunners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugCMXct4nrs), waveboards and longboards, scooters... I need to pick one that is

- Fast (my goal is cutting travel time, after all)
- Small, so that I can take it with me on a train. Moscow Metro doesn't allow bicycles, because [this](http://img0.joyreactor.cc/pics/post/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE-1889217.jpeg).

What would be my best bet?

Comment: If the station is that crowed then I would guess the sidewalks are crowed.   How crowed and what is the tarmac like on the two segments?

Comment: No, it is not _that_ crazy usually, the picture was taken during an incident that led to such a crowd. But incidents like that happen like once a year so there are precautions.

Comment: OK, but that does not answer the question on street conditions.

Comment: The crowded stations are the transit ones: those where people change trains. The ones I travel from and to are pretty empty. The sidewalks where I walk are usually quite deserted as well.

Comment: Ah, and both segments are asphalt sidewalks

Comment: Are folding bikes allowed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this (great) question as off-topic because it is specifically not about bikes. (But I have also up voted it as it is a very good question). Is there a better SE site for it?

Comment: This question belongs on [LifeHacks](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You forgot hoverboards.

Comment: @dlu Yes, they are

Comment: @andy256 Good suggestion! [Posted it](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9708/skateboard-roller-blades-or). Let's see how it works

Comment: In The Netherlands and in China (Beijing at least) I was able to buy a very simple second hand bike for something €40 (NL) and €15 (CN). If the situation is the same in Moscow, couldn't you just buy two second hand bikes: one for the home segment, one for the work segment? In the long run it definitely beats the renting price. Also: check out [freeline skates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeline_skates)

Comment: @BartArondson Rent is RUB600 (~USD10) a month, used bikes start from RUB2500. It saves money, but this is for a pretty old bike and it's way less flexible than rent (lets you get a bike at any of the 300 stations for short under-30-min rides, which is always enough to get to/from a metro station)

Answer (score 3):

Boards are bad because you can't stop quickly.

Skates are bad because they're a pain to put on and take off.

I would go with either a heavy-duty folding scooter or a folding bike. Both are fast and reasonably small.

Answer (score 3):

Turning this into a Bicycles question - Do they have (safe/secure) stands/storage  at the local station. Ride your bike to the station, leave it there, get on the train, ride a city bike to your destination.

Comment: Check the question. Rental available for home segment.

Comment: There are bike racks near stations and at my destination. So, in theory, I can buy a bike, park it near the station I arrive at use it. Haven't thought of it! Not sure this is the best option though. I would have to buy a bicycle _and_ pay for rental.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using both rollerblades and [city bikes](http://velib.fr) for my daily commute when the weather is fine, for about two years.

For both modes my 12 km commute is approx. 40-45 min, i.e. about 20 km/h. The subway takes about 1 hour for the same route. For a kilometer you'd take about 10 minutes including putting your shoes on and off.

I have a clear preference for rollerblades since they are so much smaller. I have a [special backpack](http://www.wl33.com/image/cache/data/POWERSLIDE/powerslide-sportbag2-750x750.jpg) in which I can store my skates when I an not using them and my regular shoes when I am. On the other hand, they take longer to brake and generally require you to pay a bit more attention to the road.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a bicycle question and it should get closed but I would do skate board. Way quicker to change compared to skates and less volume.  The longer the board the better it roles but harder it is pack.  Go with the biggest board would you want to pack.  A good skate shop will be able to tell you a good street board.  It is not going to be quicker until you get good on the board.

Comment: There are also adult sized kick scooters with fold down handlebars (like the kids scooters but with a longer platform & bigger wheels), I think Razer makes one, as well as Xooter & I'm sure many others

Comment: @renesis Scooter is not nearly as efficient.   A skate board holds direction fine and and you can put your body into a more natural motion and use upper body strength like you do running or even walking.  Skate board has more wheel surface on the ground to deal with anomalies.

Comment: Frisbee, do you have any evidence for that claim? I've never been on a board that I felt was more efficient or better handing than a proper sized scooter. Anyway, I second the board option for it being so ready to get off of, picking up milk on your way home will be a pain if you have skates on.

Comment: @Carl Do you evidence to the contrary.

Comment: Only my own experience, I had both as a teenager ( not a long board though ).  The six inch inflatable tires of the scooter made it much better versed as a transport device.  It was just harder to deal with after it had done it's job.

Answer (score 0):

Skate or Die... Similar answer but I suggest getting a short board with 58mm+ wheels (you will need risers) and FAST bearings. From experience... It's versatile, maneuverable, compact, and good protection. Most of all it's fun.

PS:
Maybe try either the Sports or Physical Fitness sites.